# How do I pull multiple bible verses from a text file?

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying to write something that will cite (from a text file) verses upon request from the user.
I've got something that can successfully do this, but only for singular verses.

```
userinput = input("Enter Book, Chapter, Verse:")
file = open("CNT.txt")
lines = file.readlines()
for line in lines:
    if userinput in line:
        print(line)
        break

file.close()
```

The text in the text file looks like this:

> Rev 6:1 Then I saw when the Lamb opened one of the seven seals, and I heard one of the four living creatures saying with a voice like thunder: "Come!" 
> Rev 6:2 And I saw, and behold! A white horse, and he sitting upon it having a bow, and a crown has been given to him and he went out conquering and that he may conquer. 
> Rev 6:3 And when He opened the second seal, I heard the second living creature saying "Come!"

I'm very new to this, and I'm sure that shows. Is there any way to add to or change this code to allow it to fetch multiple verses when the user inputs things like "Rev 6:1-3" or "Rev 6:1,3"? Or should it be discarded altogether in favor of something more effective and complex?

Comment: You'll need to do parsing for the user input to get the effective list of verses that the use wants. For example. "Rev 6:1-3" will need to be parsed into `["Rev 6:1", "Rev 6:2", "Rev 6:3"]` After that. It's a matter of running your search with the list instead of a single input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an answer for you based on your code and the comment above.

```
userinput = input("Enter Book, Chapter, Verse:")
d = userinput.find("-")

if d == -1:
    verses = [userinput]
else:
    book_chapter = userinput[:userinput.find(":")]
    first_verse = userinput[userinput.find(":") + 1:d]
    last_verse = userinput[d + 1:]
    verses = [book_chapter + ":" + str(x) for x in range(int(first_verse),int(last_verse)+1)]

file = open("CNT.txt")
lines = file.readlines()
for line in lines:
    if any([x in line for x in verses]):
        print(line)

file.close()
```

This doesn't have any error handling or any tolerance of slight variations in format, but hopefully it gives you the idea and helps you learn the language. Names of some of the things I've used that you might want to read up on are:

1. Substrings, for example `userinput[:3]`
2. String methods such as `userinput.find(":")`
3. List comprehensions `[x in line for x in verses]`
4. `if/else` blocks

Another thing to note is that this is pretty inefficient. I suspect with the whole bible this will be pretty slow. This is because you are searching the whole text for every verse reference. You are not taking advantage of the fact you know they occur at the start of lines or in order. This is what data structures such as Python's dict or SQL databases are made for, maybe check them out.